# What does "starred" mean?

Tags: support, badges, chat

So there is the [**Talkative** badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731) on Stack Overflow.
It says:

> Post 10 messages, with 1 or more **starred**, in chat.

What does **starred** even mean?

Comment: This are stars: http://41.media.tumblr.com/096cd41feb6f549d5fa593edab085c9d/tumblr_mi8pp5cfry1s55xmso1_500.png (<- To be precise, this is *star wars*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click the Star in a message in chat to get the message on the starboard at the right:

[image]

In the above screenshot you see 8 starred messages (that form a [train](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/ok))

Comment: OK​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @CodyGray: Here you are: ★